# С помощью какого модуля я могу узнать температуру/загрузку процессора и видеокарты на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cpu, gpu

В интернете ответы находил, но модули либо имели проблемы с `Windows 10` (На которой я работаю), либо просто выводили не ту информацию что мне нужна.

Посоветуйте что-нибудь годное.

Answer (score 0):

Например, с помощью модуля pyspectator
https://pypi.org/project/pyspectator/

или с помощью psutil
https://pypi.org/project/psutil/
.

Answer (score 0):

```
import psutil

print(psutil.cpu_percent())  # windows
print(psutil.sensors_temperatures())  # только для Linux
```