# Как в Python получить загрузку процессора?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, процессор, psutil

Нужно получить загрузку *CPU*, но так, чтобы значение совпало с тем что в диспетчере задач.

Пробовал много вариантов кода с использованием модуля **`psutil`**, но видимо я что-то делаю не так.

Были такие варианты (не все):

```
import psutil
import time

while True:
    cpu_percent = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
    print(f"Использование процессора: {cpu_percent}%")
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

```
import wmi
import time

c = wmi.WMI()

while True:
    for cpu in c.Win32_Processor():
        print(f"Использование процессора: {cpu.LoadPercentage}%")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Я даже специально использовал программу для нагрузки, и когда в дз нагрузка колебается от 50 до 60 %, то в консоли программы она 10 - 40%. Для меня такая разница - критична, даже начинает казаться, что библиотека берёт значения из воздуха.

Comment: Одно из объяснений для различий может быть использование разного интервала измерения. В вашем коде вы используете интервал в 1 секунду (interval=1). Длина интервала измерения может влиять на точность и стабильность получаемых значений. Попробуйте увеличить интервал, например, до 5 секунд:

Comment: вот еще упоминают pyspectator https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1116255/%d0%a1-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80

Comment: @Exord нет, всё равно разница на 10-15% меньше

Comment: @Эникейщик кое как установил библиотеку, она не работала, пришлось самому исправлять там ошибку и тоже напрасно, на 10-15% меньше чем на самом деле

Comment: я по этой библиотеке полазил и понял что она посути и использует psutil, так что смысла нет

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, я не проверял ваши примеры, т.к. иногда пользуюсь приложением написанным на **`PyQt`**. Показывает вроде нормально. 
Попробуйте проверить у себя.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
import os
import psutil                                         # pip install psutil
import platform
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
import pyqtgraph as pg

from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow

import numpy as np
from collections import deque


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        
        self.traces = dict()
        self.timestamp = 0
        self.timeaxis = []
        self.cpuaxis = []
        self.ramaxis = []

        self.current_timer_graph = None
        self.graph_lim = 15
        self.deque_timestamp = deque([], maxlen=self.graph_lim+20)
        self.deque_cpu = deque([], maxlen=self.graph_lim+20)
        self.deque_ram = deque([], maxlen=self.graph_lim+20)
        self.ui.label.setText(
            f"{platform.system()} {platform.machine()}")
        self.ui.label_2.setText(
            f"Processor: {platform.processor()}")

        self.graphwidget1 = PlotWidget(title="CPU percent")
        x1_axis = self.graphwidget1.getAxis('bottom')
        x1_axis.setLabel(text='Time since start (s)')
        y1_axis = self.graphwidget1.getAxis('left')
        y1_axis.setLabel(text='Percent')

        self.graphwidget2 = PlotWidget(title="RAM percent")
        x2_axis = self.graphwidget2.getAxis('bottom')
        x2_axis.setLabel(text='Time since start (s)')
        y2_axis = self.graphwidget2.getAxis('left')
        y2_axis.setLabel(text='Percent')

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_cpu_graph)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.show_ram_graph)
        
        self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graphwidget1, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graphwidget2, 0, 0, 1, 3)

        self.current_timer_systemStat = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.current_timer_systemStat.timeout.connect(
            self.getsystemStatpercent)
        self.current_timer_systemStat.start(1000)

        self.getsystemStatpercent() 
        self.show_cpu_graph()

    def getsystemStatpercent(self):
        self.cpu_percent = psutil.cpu_percent()
        self.ram_percent = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
        self.setValue(self.cpu_percent, self.ui.labelPercentageCPU,
                      self.ui.circularProgressCPU, "rgba(85, 170, 255, 255)")
        self.setValue(self.ram_percent, self.ui.labelPercentageRAM,
                      self.ui.circularProgressRAM, "rgba(255, 0, 127, 255)")

    def start_cpu_graph(self):
        if self.current_timer_graph:
            self.current_timer_graph.stop()
            self.current_timer_graph.deleteLater()
            self.current_timer_graph = None
            
        self.current_timer_graph = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.current_timer_graph.timeout.connect(self.update_cpu)
        self.current_timer_graph.start(1000)

    def update_cpu(self):
        self.timestamp += 1
        self.deque_timestamp.append(self.timestamp)
        self.deque_cpu.append(self.cpu_percent)
        self.deque_ram.append(self.ram_percent)
        timeaxis_list = list(self.deque_timestamp)
        cpu_list = list(self.deque_cpu)

        if self.timestamp > self.graph_lim:
            self.graphwidget1.setRange(
                xRange=[self.timestamp-self.graph_lim+1, self.timestamp], 
                yRange=[min(cpu_list[-self.graph_lim:]), max(cpu_list[-self.graph_lim:])]
            )
        self.set_plotdata(name="cpu", data_x=timeaxis_list, data_y=cpu_list)

    def start_ram_graph(self):
        if self.current_timer_graph:
            self.current_timer_graph.stop()
            self.current_timer_graph.deleteLater()
            self.current_timer_graph = None
        self.current_timer_graph = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.current_timer_graph.timeout.connect(self.update_ram)
        self.current_timer_graph.start(1000)

    def update_ram(self):
        self.timestamp += 1

        self.deque_timestamp.append(self.timestamp)
        self.deque_cpu.append(self.cpu_percent)
        self.deque_ram.append(self.ram_percent)
        timeaxis_list = list(self.deque_timestamp)
        ram_list = list(self.deque_ram)

        if self.timestamp > self.graph_lim:
            self.graphwidget2.setRange(
                xRange=[self.timestamp-self.graph_lim+1, self.timestamp], 
                yRange=[min(ram_list[-self.graph_lim:]), max(ram_list[-self.graph_lim:])]
            )
        self.set_plotdata(name="ram", data_x=timeaxis_list,
                          data_y=ram_list)

    def show_cpu_graph(self):
        self.graphwidget2.hide()
        self.graphwidget1.show()
        self.start_cpu_graph()
        self.ui.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color : lightblue;}")
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                background-color: rgb(255, 44, 174);
                color : white;
            }
        """)

    def show_ram_graph(self):
        self.graphwidget1.hide()
        self.graphwidget2.show()
        self.start_ram_graph()
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton" "{" "background-color : lightblue;" "}"
        )
        self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton"
            "{"
            "background-color : rgba(85, 170, 255, 255);"
            "}"
            "QPushButton"
            "{"
            "color : white;"
            "}"
        )

    def set_plotdata(self, name, data_x, data_y):
        if name in self.traces:
            self.traces[name].setData(data_x, data_y)
        else:
            if name == "cpu":
                self.traces[name] = self.graphwidget1.getPlotItem().plot(
                    pen=pg.mkPen((85, 170, 255), width=3))

            elif name == "ram":
                self.traces[name] = self.graphwidget2.getPlotItem().plot(
                    pen=pg.mkPen((255, 0, 127), width=3))

    def setValue(self, value, labelPercentage, progressBarName, color):
        sliderValue = value
        htmlText = """
            <p align="center">
                <span style=" font-size:50pt;">{VALUE}</span>
                <span style=" font-size:40pt; vertical-align:super;">%</span>
            </p>
        """
        labelPercentage.setText(htmlText.replace(
            "{VALUE}", f"{sliderValue:.1f}"))
        self.progressBarValue(sliderValue, progressBarName, color)

    def progressBarValue(self, value, widget, color):
        styleSheet = """
        QFrame{
            border-radius: 110px;
            background-color: qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:90, stop:{STOP_1} rgba(255, 0, 127, 0), stop:{STOP_2} {COLOR});
        }
        """
        progress = (100 - value) / 100.0
        stop_1 = str(progress - 0.001)
        stop_2 = str(progress)

        if value == 100:
            stop_1 = "1.000"
            stop_2 = "1.000"

        newStylesheet = styleSheet.replace("{STOP_1}", stop_1).replace(
            "{STOP_2}", stop_2).replace("{COLOR}", color)

        widget.setStyleSheet(newStylesheet)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main_ui.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(760, 480)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(760, 480))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(760, 480))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(77, 77, 127);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.circularProgressBar_Main = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.circularProgressBar_Main.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 240, 240))
        self.circularProgressBar_Main.setStyleSheet("background-color: none;")
        self.circularProgressBar_Main.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.circularProgressBar_Main.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.circularProgressBar_Main.setObjectName("circularProgressBar_Main")
        self.circularProgressCPU = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.circularProgressBar_Main)
        self.circularProgressCPU.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 220, 220))
        self.circularProgressCPU.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"    border-radius: 110px;    \n"
"    background-color: qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:90, stop:0.400 rgba(85, 170, 255, 255), stop:0.395 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));\n"
"}")
        self.circularProgressCPU.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.circularProgressCPU.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.circularProgressCPU.setObjectName("circularProgressCPU")
        self.circularBg = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.circularProgressBar_Main)
        self.circularBg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 220, 220))
        self.circularBg.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"    border-radius: 110px;    \n"
"    background-color: rgba(85, 85, 127, 100);\n"
"}")
        self.circularBg.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.circularBg.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.circularBg.setObjectName("circularBg")
        self.circularContainer = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.circularProgressBar_Main)
        self.circularContainer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 25, 190, 190))
        self.circularContainer.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.circularContainer.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"    border-radius: 95px;    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(58, 58, 102);\n"
"}")
        self.circularContainer.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.circularContainer.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.circularContainer.setObjectName("circularContainer")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.circularContainer)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 171, 125))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.infoLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.infoLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.infoLayout.setObjectName("infoLayout")
        self.labelAplicationName = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Helvetica Neue")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.labelAplicationName.setFont(font)
        self.labelAplicationName.setStyleSheet("color: #FFFFFF; background-color: none;")
        self.labelAplicationName.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelAplicationName.setObjectName("labelAplicationName")
        self.infoLayout.addWidget(self.labelAplicationName, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.labelPercentageCPU = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Helvetica Neue")
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.labelPercentageCPU.setFont(font)
        self.labelPercentageCPU.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(115, 185, 255); padding: 0px; background-color: none;")
        self.labelPercentageCPU.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelPercentageCPU.setIndent(-1)
        self.labelPercentageCPU.setObjectName("labelPercentageCPU")
        self.infoLayout.addWidget(self.labelPercentageCPU, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.labelCredits = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Helvetica Neue")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.labelCredits.setFont(font)
        self.labelCredits.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(148, 148, 216); background-color: none;")
        self.labelCredits.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelCredits.setObjectName("labelCredits")
        self.infoLayout.addWidget(self.labelCredits, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.circularBg.raise_()
        self.circularProgressCPU.raise_()
        self.circularContainer.raise_()
        self.circularProgressBar_Main_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.circularProgressBar_Main_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 60, 240, 240))
        self.circularProgressBar_Main_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: none;")
        self.circularProgressBar_Main_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.circularProgressBar_Main_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.circularProgressBar_Main_3.setObjectName("circularProgressBar_Main_3")
        self.circularProgressRAM = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.circularProgressBar_Main_3)
        self.circularProgressRAM.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 220, 220))
        self.circularProgressRAM.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"    border-radius: 110px;    \n"
"    background-color: qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:90, stop:0.750 rgba(255, 0, 127, 255), stop:0.745 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));\n"
"}")
        self.circularProgressRAM.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.circularProgressRAM.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.circularProgressRAM.setObjectName("circularProgressRAM")
        self.circularBg_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.circularProgressBar_Main_3)
        self.circularBg_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 220, 220))
        self.circularBg_3.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"    border-radius: 110px;    \n"
"    background-color: rgba(85, 85, 127, 100);\n"
"}")
        self.circularBg_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.circularBg_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.circularBg_3.setObjectName("circularBg_3")
        self.circularContainer_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.circularProgressBar_Main_3)
        self.circularContainer_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 25, 190, 190))
        self.circularContainer_3.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.circularContainer_3.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"    border-radius: 95px;    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(58, 58, 102);\n"
"}")
        self.circularContainer_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.circularContainer_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.circularContainer_3.setObjectName("circularContainer_3")
        self.layoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.circularContainer_3)
        self.layoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 171, 125))
        self.layoutWidget_3.setObjectName("layoutWidget_3")
        self.infoLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.infoLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.infoLayout_3.setObjectName("infoLayout_3")
        self.labelAplicationName_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Helvetica Neue")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.labelAplicationName_3.setFont(font)
        self.labelAplicationName_3.setStyleSheet("color: #FFFFFF; background-color: none;")
        self.labelAplicationName_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelAplicationName_3.setObjectName("labelAplicationName_3")
        self.infoLayout_3.addWidget(self.labelAplicationName_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.labelPercentageRAM = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Helvetica Neue")
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.labelPercentageRAM.setFont(font)
        self.labelPercentageRAM.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 44, 174); padding: 0px; background-color: none;")
        self.labelPercentageRAM.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelPercentageRAM.setIndent(-1)
        self.labelPercentageRAM.setObjectName("labelPercentageRAM")
        self.infoLayout_3.addWidget(self.labelPercentageRAM, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.labelCredits_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Helvetica Neue")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.labelCredits_3.setFont(font)
        self.labelCredits_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(148, 148, 216); background-color: none;")
        self.labelCredits_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelCredits_3.setObjectName("labelCredits_3")
        self.infoLayout_3.addWidget(self.labelCredits_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.circularBg_3.raise_()
        self.circularProgressRAM.raise_()
        self.circularContainer_3.raise_()
        self.label_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 10, 641, 50))
        self.label_title.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(115, 185, 255); background-color: none; font-size: 22px;")
        self.label_title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_title.setObjectName("label_title")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 320, 721, 151))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 160, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(85, 170, 255, 255);\n"
"color: white;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 200, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 44, 174);\n"
"color: white;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 60, 341, 16))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(115, 185, 255); font-size: 12px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px; border: none;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 90, 241, 16))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(115, 185, 255); font-size: 12px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px; border: none;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "System Monitor"))
        self.labelAplicationName.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<strong>CPU</strong> USAGE"))
        self.labelPercentageCPU.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:50pt;\">60</span><span style=\" font-size:40pt; vertical-align:super;\">%</span></p>"))
        self.labelCredits.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.labelAplicationName_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<strong>RAM</strong> USAGE"))
        self.labelPercentageRAM.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:50pt;\">25</span><span style=\" font-size:40pt; vertical-align:super;\">%</span></p>"))
        self.labelCredits_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "System Monitor"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show CPU Graph"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show RAM Graph"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Darwin"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Processor"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, но нет, и тут разница в 10-20%. Посмотрев Ваш код я понял что и тут используется библиотека psutil, поэтому ничего не поменялось...